# Comparing two indices in an array in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

I'm currently writing a program in assembly that will "reverse" the order of a string.

My string is stored in the `ebx` register.
The current count is stored in the `ecx` register and the 
string length is stored in the `eax` register.
I'm confused about how to access the element at the 'count' position in the ebx and at another element in the array.
in psuedo code

```
int count = 0;
int rcount = myString.length() - 1;
while(count < rcount)
    myString[count] ^= myString[rcount];
    myString[rcount] ^= myString[count];
    myString[count] ^= myString[rcount];
    count++;
    rcount--;
```

the ^= operator is an xor statement. 
so in assembly it would be along the lines of(with improper coding I don't know how to access arrays in assembly)

```
 xor ebx[count], ebx[rcount]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XOR swap is not very useful in this case. Just load the 2 items into 2 registers and write them out swapped. For example:

```
mov al, [ebx + ecx] ; assume ecx = count
mov ah, [ebx + edx] ; assume edx = rcount
mov [ebx + ecx], ah ; write out
mov [ebx + edx], al ; swapped
```

Answer (score 2):

The **swap** can be written in as few as 3 instructions.

> My string is stored in the **ebx** register.
>   The current count is stored in the **ecx** register and the string length is stored in the **eax** register.

This code will reverse the string:

```
     test eax, eax
     jz   ready
     xor  ecx,ecx
     jmp  next
swap:
     mov  dl, [ebx+ecx]   \
     xchg dl, [ebx+eax]   | The swap
     mov  [ebx+ecx], dl   /
     inc  ecx
next:
     dec  eax
     cmp  ecx, eax
     jb   swap
ready:
```

---

A better version (longer but **much faster**) will avoid the use of the slow memory-`xchg` instruction and will process 8 characters at a time by means of the `bswap` instruction. A *cool trick* as suggested by Peter Cordes.

I've used the same register layout as before:

```
      test  eax, eax
      jz    ready
      mov   edx, eax       ;EDX=Remaining string length
      xor   ecx, ecx
      jmp   nextD
swapD:
      sub   eax, 4
      mov   esi, [ebx+ecx]
      mov   edi, [ebx+eax]
      bswap esi
      bswap edi
      mov   [ebx+eax], esi
      mov   [ebx+ecx], edi
      add   ecx, 4
nextD:
      sub   edx, 8
      jnb   swapD

      jmp   nextB
swapB:
      mov   dl, [ebx+ecx]
      mov   dh, [ebx+eax]
      mov   [ebx+eax], dl
      mov   [ebx+ecx], dh
      inc   ecx
nextB:
      dec   eax
      cmp   ecx, eax
      jb    swapB
ready:
```

I tested both versions on an alphabet string (so 26 bytes in the string) and I got a **64%** speed increase!

Comment: That's true if you want to force a very-slow atomic read-modify-write exchange, with a full memory barrier, by using `xchg` with a memory operand.  The `lock` prefix is implicit in that case.  If you want to show the OP a cool trick, maybe code up the loop to reverse 4 or 8 bytes at a time with `bswap` or `movbe` (until you get within 4B of the middle).

Comment: @PeterCordes Here http://zsmith.co/intel_x.html#xchg it says 5 cycles since 80286, but I am not trying to prove you wrong. I really am curious what makes it very-slow?

Comment: 486 didn't have out-of-order execution at all, or multiple cores with multiple levels of cache to synchronize!  http://agner.org/optimize/ says that on Intel Skylake, `xchg r,m` is 8 uops, with 23 cycle latency.  `lock add` for example has one per 18c throughput.  Compare this with a normal load or store being 1 uop, with a max throughput of two loads and one store per cycle.  Even this doesn't account for the potential slowdown of the memory fence that's part of a `lock`ed instruction, if other cores have busy dirtying their caches.

Comment: @Pyjong: compared to other architectures, x86 generally has fast atomic operations, but they still have a large performance penalty compared to non-atomic.

Comment: Nice.  The `swapB` loop might be faster on some CPUs if you used separate registers, instead of `dh` and `dl`.  AMD CPUs, and Silvermont, will have a false dependency in each write to a part of `edx`.  You could also use simpler addressing modes:  inc/dec pointers instead of indices.  two-register store uops can't micro-fuse on Intel SnB.  Anyway, I expected a much bigger speedup from avoiding `xchg` and using a 4B loop, but maybe there's a lot of other overhead with such tiny strings?  Thanks for posting the number.