# Strange execution times on string reversal

Tags: string, assembly, x86, timing

Last week I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399412/comparing-two-indices-in-an-array-in-assembly/35411750#35411750) and its accompanying comments about a string
reversal routine.
I decided to test it myself and stumbled upon an apparent anomalie.
For some reason the second routine performs very differently depending on
the length of the string being shorter than 128 bytes or not.

```
   UsingXchg              UsingMov              UsingBswap

   add   eax, ebx         add   eax, ebx        mov   edx, eax
   jmp   B                jmp   B               add   eax, ebx
A: mov   dl, [ebx]     A: mov   dl, [ebx]       jmp   B
   xchg  dl, [eax]        mov   cl, [eax]    A: sub   eax, 4
   mov   [ebx], dl        mov   [eax], dl       mov   esi, [ebx]
   inc   ebx              mov   [ebx], cl       mov   edi, [eax]
B: dec   eax              inc   ebx             bswap esi
   cmp   ebx, eax      B: dec   eax             bswap edi
   jb    A                cmp   ebx, eax        mov   [eax], esi
                          jb    A               mov   [ebx], edi
                                                add   ebx, 4
                                             B: sub   edx, 8
                                                jnb   A
                                                jmp   D
   On entry: EBX is address                  C: mov   dl, [ebx]
             EAX is length                      mov   cl, [eax]
                                                mov   [eax], dl
                                                mov   [ebx], cl
                                                inc   ebx
                                             D: dec   eax
                                                cmp   ebx, eax
                                                jb    C
```

Next come the times (in msec) I measured for a large number of repeats.

```
StringSize     UsingXchg   UsingMov    UsingBswap

   26             30.7        17.4         6.4
   52             60.9        33.4        12.2
   78             90.5        49.4        17.9
  104            121.9        65.4        22.7
                            /------\
  127                       | 79.0 |
  128                       | 27.3 |
                            \------/
  130            152.1        27.6        27.9
  156            181.9        30.7        33.5
  182            211.8        34.4        39.2
  208            241.8        37.2        44.0

  260            301.6        43.6        54.9
 2600           2996.5       337.2       538.4
26000          29949.2      3226.5      5350.4
```

- Both *UsingXchg* and *UsingBswap* show regularity, but *UsingMov* clearly
  shifts gear at the 128 bytes mark.
  I suspect caches are at the heart of this little problem, *but then why don't
  all 3 routines show the same effect?*
- I'd like to conclude that the best string reversal routine is *UsingBswap*
  with a bypass in case the string has more than 127 bytes.
  *Would this be a valid conclusion at all?*

  ```
     mov   edx, eax  ;Remaining string length
     add   eax, ebx  ;Turn EAX into a pointer
     cmp   edx, 127
     ja    D         ;Don't use Bswap on long strings
     jmp   B
  A: sub   eax, 4
     ...
  D: dec   eax
     cmp   ebx, eax
     jb    C         ;Still 2 bytes left
  ```